# Textbox enabled based on Select dynamically and apply validation on textbox

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

Want enable textbox based on dropdown select dynamic id generated. Textbox and Select box id is generated dynamically like.. amount1, amount2, amount3 and apply validation on textbox with maximum of 3000 amount. For Example : Ehen user select, value as "Fines" in textbox value should allow between 1 to 3000 and text. if select values as other then "Fines" then no validation on textbox.

My Javascript Code :

```
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.amount').attr('disabled', true);
  $(".amount").css({ "backgroundColor": "#eee" });
});

$(document).ready(function () {
    $('input[name=amount]').keyup(function () {
        var total_items = 100;
        for (rowNum = 1; rowNum <= total_items; rowNum++) {
            var selectvl = $("#exp_id" + rowNum).val();
            if (selectvl == '10') {
                if ($(this).val() < 3001 && $(this).val() > 1) {
                    $('#msg').fadeOut('slow');
                } else {
                    $('#msg').fadeIn('slow');
                }
                } 
            }   
    });

    $('body').on('change', '.exp_id', function () {
        var total_items = 100;
        for (rowNum = 1; rowNum <= total_items; rowNum++) {
        const toChangeElement = $(event.target).parent().next().children();
            const exp_id = event.target.value;
            if (this.value == '10') {
                $("#amount" + rowNum).attr('max', '3000');
                $("#amount" + rowNum).attr('min', '1');
                $('#msg').fadeIn('slow');
                $("#msg").html("Enter amount below AED 3000. !!");
                $("#amount" + rowNum).css({ "backgroundColor": "#ffffff" );
                toChangeElement.removeAttr('disabled');
                toChangeElement.css('backgroundColor', "#ffffff");
                toChangeElement.focus();
                return false;
            } else {
                $('#msg').fadeOut('slow');
                $("#amount" + rowNum).attr('max', '10000');
                $("#amount" + rowNum).attr('min', '1');
                $("#amount" + rowNum).css({"backgroundColor": "#ffffff"});
                toChangeElement.removeAttr('disabled');
                toChangeElement.css('backgroundColor', "#ffffff");
                toChangeElement.focus();
            }
        }
    });
});
```

[My jsfiddle link](https://jsfiddle.net/rakeshkumar29594/1ob0s4kq/10/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You dont need to run a loop there,we can fix this in a easy way

check the fiddle [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/m2gn06zy/1/).

As of now, if the value from the select option is `10`, then only the input will become enabled. you can add you logic also in here.

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.amount').attr('disabled', true);
  $(".amount").css({
    "backgroundColor": "#eee"
  });
});

function updateCheckBox() {
  var total_items = 100;
  const toChangeElement = $(event.target).parent().next().children();
  const exp_id = event.target.value;
  if (exp_id == '10') {
    toChangeElement.removeAttr('disabled');
    toChangeElement.css('backgroundColor', "#ffffff");
    toChangeElement.focus();
  } else {
    toChangeElement.val('');
    toChangeElement.attr('disabled', 'disabled');
    toChangeElement.css('backgroundColor', "#eee");
  }
  /* for (var rowNum = 1; rowNum <= total_items; rowNum++) {
    exp_id = $('#exp_id' + rowNum).val();
    if (exp_id == '10') {
      $('#amount' + rowNum).attr('disabled', false);
      $("#amount" + rowNum).css({ "backgroundColor": "#ffffff" });
      return false;
    
    } else {  
      $('#amount' + rowNum).attr('disabled', false);
      $("#amount" + rowNum).css({ "backgroundColor": "#ffffff" });
      return false;
    }
  } */
}
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="bs-example">
        <form id="sendform" method="post" action="#" autocomplete="off">
          <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>Select</th>
                <th>Amount</th>
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <select id="exp_id1" class="form-control exp_id" required name="exp_id" onchange="updateCheckBox()">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select one</option>
                    <option value="10">Fines</option>
                    <option value="11">Medical</option>
                    <option value="12">Parking</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control amount" id="amount1"></td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <select id="exp_id2" class="form-control exp_id" required name="exp_id" onchange="updateCheckBox()">
                    <option value="" selected disabled>Select one</option>
                    <option value="10">Fines</option>
                    <option value="11">Medical</option>
                    <option value="12">Parking</option>
                  </select>
                </td>
                <td><input type="number" name="amount" class="form-control amount" id="amount2"></td>
              </tr>
            </tbody>
          </table>
          <div class="checkbox">
            <div id="msg" style="color:#990000; font-size:14px;"></div>
          </div>
          <br>
          <button type="submit" name="submit_row" value="Submit" class="btn btn-primary">SUBMIT</button>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you, I am sorry I have asked question little different way, I have updated my fiddler. Requirement is when user select, value as "Fines" in textbox value should allow between 1 to 3000 and text. if select values as other then "Fines" then no validation on textbox.

Comment: [Revised fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/rakeshkumar29594/1ob0s4kq/7/)

Comment: And when user select that particular select box that time only that next text-box should enabled not all ..

Comment: @Rakesh sohe how you have to take some effort from you end also, updating questions with new work around on solving previous queries is like making some one do your home work.

Comment: I have updated questions as well, see if you can help me. Thank you

Comment: any help brother ?

Comment: @Rakesh check the updated fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/9Lv71xb8/1/

Comment: @Rakesh please accept my answer and give an upvote if this ans was helpful, that will be an appretiation for my efforrt :)

Comment: Answer Accepted, Thank you Akhil

Comment: Akhil need small help,  want to set maxlength if user select as value **Fines** then maxlength is **4** otherwise **10** and it should allows only numeric value

Comment: are you there to help on last task ?